# GraphQL filter/order based on result count of relation

Tags: graphql, prisma, apollo-client

I am kind of new to GraphQL world and i am stuck at a, i would say, very basic problem. I dug around couple of docs and guides and i could not find any hint if it is even possible or not with GraphQL or what might be a workaround.

What i want to achieve, is a simple query, from a *famous* example (Post/Author) found on various guides: `get all authors with more than one post` or at least `get all authors sorted by their count of posts`.

It is meant from the perspective of consuming a GraphQL from the browser. I know it might also depend on the GraphQL server implementation, i am using Prisma. But also hints to solutions in whatever server solution are appreciated.

After quite some digging i found no hints if something like this might be possible and where to start even. I wonder if that is such a special use-case that it is not mentioned at all in any guide i found. So quite frankly i am not sure how to tackle this. Is it even possible? If not what might a workaround be? Filtering after the query might not work, because of course a scenario with thousands of authors come to mind, where pagination and performance might collapse.

```
model User {
  id                          String              @id @default(cuid())
  name                        String              @default("")
  email                       String              @unique @default("")
  password                    String
  posts                       Post[]              @relation("Post_author")
  createdAt                   DateTime?           @default(now())
}

model Post {
  id       String  @id @default(cuid())
  title    String  @default("")
  content  Json    @default("[{\"type\":\"paragraph\",\"children\":[{\"text\":\"\"}]}]")
  author   User?   @relation("Post_author", fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId String? @map("author")
  tags     Tag[]   @relation("Post_tags")

  @@index([authorId])
}
```

Any help appreciated.